# Smart Stack + Docker

Tags: architecture, cloud, docker

I am working on a proof of concept project using Smart Stack (from airbnb) and Docker to build distributed service cloud.

I have 3 services:

1. one for building the frontend the application
2. one for user login
3. one for the domain operations

The frontend application obviously uses the other two services.

I am planning to deploy all the 3 using docker, and to use smartstack to make the distributed service discovery dynamic.

As far as I understand Docker, the best approach (if not the only one) for using it, is having only one process running for each container.

And Smart Stack is built putting 3 auxiliary processes (nerve, synapse, haproxy) at the same machine as the main service is running.

So, here goes my question: does it make any sense to use Docker and Smart Stack altogether? If so, how do people do that? 4 processes at one Docker container?

What are the best design patterns for such an architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the architecture, inside container (LXC or docker) you only need nerve. Nerve is a registration daemon. It works independently from your service or application, just inform Service Discovery on which port its running.

Depends of which Service Discovery you gonna choose you need different architecture
* Zookeeper - to avoiding split brain - odd number of servers n*2+1 like 3 to get quorum
* Serf - is distributed and efficient one
* etcd and more 
check this out:
http://www.activestate.com/blog/2014/05/service-discovery-solutions

Then at the end you need synapse with HAProxy (put them together somewhere, can be on a separate host(s))
Synapse gets information form Zookeeper/Serf how services looks like
and generate dynamic config for HAproxy.

If you use Serf you need to use different branch
(https://github.com/getyourguide/synapse/tree/serf )

You can also try this project: http://gilliam.github.io/
which gonna give you last piece of your cloud
deploying and managing (check scheduler form this project)

Comment: Supplement:
In docker by default you don't have routeable network,
you can use [piperwork](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) project that will solve this problem